# Indentation of examples with Linguex and Brill typeface

Tags: linguex

The text of examples is too close to the example number with example numbers having three or more digits. The problem relates to the use of the Brill font, as it disappears with other fonts.

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill} 
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document} 

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{49}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very interesting question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to add `RawFeature=+tnum` when loading the font

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+tnum]{Brill} 
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{49}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\end{document}
```

[image: tnum]

Comment: This is the same as `Numbers=Monospaced`, see my answer.

Comment: You're right. I missed your edited answer while writing mine

Comment: This solution gives the correct behaviour, ie examples are indented variably according to the number of digits in the example number. Thank you very much!

Comment: So not quite the same as the solution by @egreg in terms of Numbers=Monospaced, after all. No idea why this works, though, I'd be interested to know more.

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd `Numbers=Monospaced` is exactly the same as `RawFeature=+tnum`. With my code the feature is activated only in `\ex.` statements. The “variable” indentation is due to not setting `\Exlabelwidth`.

Comment: @egreg you're absolutely right, I'd overlooked that!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in `linguex` that, for strange reasons, wants to use the minimum width of digits, instead of the maximum!

With a font such as Brill, where the minimal width digit is 1, this spoils all computations for the label width. So I redefine `\minimalwidth` to be really `\maximalwidth`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}

\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\minimalwidth}{<}{>}{}{}% it should be maximal width!

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(000)}%
}

\begin{document} 

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{49}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\end{document}
```

Note that `mathastext` should go after setting the main font.

[image]

You may prefer a different solution, using fixed width digits in the context of `\ex` (but this will change *all* numbers in the context).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}

\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\listdecl}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(000)}%
}

\begin{document} 

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{49}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}

\ex. [$_S$ [$_{NP}$ Bartoli] [$_{VP}$ zoent Pavarotti]]

\end{document}
```

[image]